# Default Ruby version on OSX Mountain Lion ? Still 1.8.x or 1.9.x?

Tags: ruby, osx-mountain-lion

What's the default Ruby version on OSX Mountain Lion ? Still 1.8.x or 1.9.x ?

Comment: Mountain Lion and Lion are different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Mountain Lion, it is Ruby 1.8.7-p358 (Tested with OS X 10.8 and 10.8.3):

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8.3
BuildVersion:   12D78
$ /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that 1.8 is very close to EOL. Anybody who's just getting into Ruby programming should pretend that it doesn't exist and go directly to 1.9 or 2.0. You can install it directly a [number of ways](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) but I'm personally a partisan of [rvm](https://rvm.io/) which not only lets you work with multiple versions but is very helpful for dealing with platform dependency issues.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch That's right, using the default ruby version is not a good idea as long as it is 1.8. I hope that OS X 10.9 will include a recent Ruby 1.9, or even 2.0.

Comment: That's true. I called `/usr/bin/ruby` as I have other versions of ruby installed via RVM, and I wanted to be sure to call the system installed version.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X 10.9.5, ruby is now 2.0!

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F34

$ /usr/bin/ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```